# How to move reviews to product description magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to know how to move reviews tab to product description. 
Here our sample site: http://www.siameyewear.com/oakley-frogskins-polished-rootbeer-bronze.html
As you can see there are 3 tab under my social share. 
 1. Product description 
 2. Reviews
 3. Product tags

I don't want our customer to click on reviews tab to show a content. Right now I just know how to remove a reviews tab but i don't know how to move it to a position i want.

My point is I want to combine number 1 and number 2 or product description and reviews together. 
If anyone know how to add a reviews to product description. Kindly please help.

Thank you

Comment: I have try to add <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_reviews') ?> on view.phtml but nothing show up.

Comment: Update Right now I know a position to add a code. Any one please let me know what code do i have to add. Thank you

Comment: I hope my answer could help you.

Comment: You should post the layout xml code for the product reviews and description blocks.

Answer (score 0):

structure is defined in design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml file.check this xml file and change the structure whatever you want.

Comment: Hi, I have use ultimo theme. There are no catalog.xml in there.

Answer (score 0):

Find the block that is rendering your product reviews in your layout xml (probably in catalog.xml or review.xml). Remove it from there and add it to the bottom of your product description block.

Comment: Hi I have use Ultimo theme there are no catalog.xml or review.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>reviews</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
```

you want to add in catalog.xml for review tab ,,,,hope this help you.....